# Does Test Send work?

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

I have several devices registered and yet whatever I enter into the tags box (including nothing) it says...

> Outcome: {0 passed, 0 failed}

... with no matching targets.

What gives?

Comment: Did you confirm that the registrations actually exist? You can do so by firing up Visual Studio 2017, going to the Server Explorer, connecting to your Azure subscription, expanding the Notification Hubs node, choosing your Notification Hub, then clicking on the Device Registrations tab.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure there were subscriptions. Does the Device Registrations tab also show installations?

Comment: Yes. I only know that because I've only used Installations, and I see a couple of entries for each of my devices (one for Native, and one for Template).

Comment: When using Installations, do you target a template using a tag with the same name as the template?

Comment: Ian, I'm not 100% sure why we even name templates. I haven't found the reason to do so. To my knowledge, you cannot address a specific template in a NotificationHub. If you target a tag, all registered templates for that tag should fire.

Comment: I see. Except Visual Studio is telling me that the template property "Tags" is depreciated! So I was wondering how else one would target a template.

Comment: That surprises me, because I don't see Tags as being deprecated in any of the docs. I know you're using Core, which is more recent than my library.

Comment: I'll use tags then. I found the registrations in the Azure tab. Thanks for that. Does it load all registrations - even if there are thousands?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. It very well may paginate since I see a "Load more" link.

Comment: Well, I hope it "Load more"s all the way to the end.

Comment: I think it adds the template name as a tag.